# Equation goes into the right column

Tags: equations, two-column

I have this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
...

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    f(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{\beta})&=\binom{m}{\boldsymbol{y}}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+y_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \frac{\Gamma(\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}{\Gamma(\beta_i)} \\
    &\qquad{} \times \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The fact is that this equation goes into the right column even if I divide it into two lines... How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

... or using a simple `align`, and replacing `|` with `\mid`,

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm} 
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to indicate width of column
\begin{align}
f(\bm{y}&\mid\bm{\alpha},\bm{\beta})= \notag\\
&\binom{m}{\bm{y}} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+y_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i)} 
\frac{\Gamma(\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}{\Gamma(\beta_i)} \notag\\
&\qquad\qquad\times 
 \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I would replace the math-old `|` character with the math-rel macro `\mid`, though,

Comment: @Mico Of course....you are free to do all the changhes :-)))

Comment: Done. :-) (changed `|` to `\mid`, and `\boldsymbol` to `\bm`)

Comment: Thank you very much... it seems to me that they have just changed the characters on the site: I now see these differents. They are similar to Calibri font.

Comment: Good eye! See [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/280525) for the full announcement.

Comment: @Mico I have not see the link....and the advice...:-))) My eyes are very very tired...and I am here for relax.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the `multline` environment instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
f(\boldsymbol{y}\mid\boldsymbol{\alpha},\boldsymbol{\beta}) = \\
\binom{m}{\boldsymbol{y}}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+y_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \frac{\Gamma(\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}{\Gamma(\beta_i)} \\
\times \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i)}{\Gamma(\alpha_i+\beta_i+\sum_{j=i}^ky_j)}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Same comment about `\mid` that has already been mentioned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, I had noticed that, but I thought it was not the main point here. I'll fix it anyway.